# CSS Fit div Height Automatically to the available space between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the **height** of my table(class="body") to fit automatically the remaining space between the header div and the footer div. Those tree div are wrapped in a div which its position is fixed and centered on the screen.

---

**Update:**

[**JSFiddle with Flex**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrquebec13/q9hnc80u/1/) OR [**JSFiddle w\o Flex**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrquebec13/k8y9uk07/3/)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&subset=greek,latin-ext');
    .dp-container {
        position: fixed;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
        background-color: #EEE;
        color: #333;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.2;
        z-index: 50;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "proxima-nova", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: auto;
        min-width: 256px;
        max-width: 666px;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 80%;
        height: 434px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .dp-header {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        margin-top: .75em;
        line-height: 1.5;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .dp-body {
        /*height: auto;*/
        /* width: 100%; */
    }
    .dp-footer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        padding: 0;
        bottom: 1em;
    }
    .dp-container a {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .dp-container a:hover {
        color: #0089ec;
    }
    /*.dp-container > * {*/
        /*margin-top: 7px;*/
    /*}*/
    .dp-container * {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .dp-title {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 60%;
        word-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
                cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dp-month:hover {
        color: #0089ec;
    }
    .dp-month {
        font-weight: 600;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dp-header .dp-year {
        color: #888;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .dp-arrow-left, .dp-arrow-right {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        top: -0.2em;
        padding: 0 .3em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dp-arrow-right {
        right: .2em;
    }
    .dp-arrow-left {
        left: .2em;
    }
    .dp-table tbody>tr {
        height: 30%;
    }
    .dp-table {
        margin: .75em 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .dp-table>tbody>tr>td, .dp-table>tbody>tr>th, .dp-table>tfoot>tr>td, .dp-table>tfoot>tr>th, .dp-table>thead>tr>td, .dp-table>thead>tr>th
    {
        border: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .dp-table td:hover {
        background-color: #b1dcfb;
    }
    .dp-table tr {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .dp-table tr>* {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dp-table th {
        color: #888;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: .75em;
        width: 12.5%;
    }
    .dp-table td>div{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
    .dp-table td>div, .dp-table th>div {
        padding: .625em 0;
    }
    .dp-table td.today>*:before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 2px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 0.5em solid #0059bc;
        border-left: .5em solid transparent;
    }
    .dp-table td[disabled] {
        color: #BBB;
    }
    .dp-table thead th {
        padding-bottom: .25em;
    }
    .dp-table tbody th {
        padding-right: .25em;
    }
    .dp-table td:hover {
        background-color: #b1dcfb;
    }
    .dp-table tr>*.selected {
        background: #0089ec;
        color: #EEE;
    }
    .dp-footer button.dp-btn {
        width: 33%;
        margin: 0 -1px;
        padding: .66em 0;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    .dp-footer button.dp-btn:hover {
        background-color: #b1dcfb;
    }
    .dp-table.dp-months-table {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .dp-table.dp-months-table tr>* {
        padding: 1.2em 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-origin: border-box;
        background-size: cover;
        font-weight: bolder;
        color: #202020;
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(84,184,242,0.91) , 1px 1px 6px rgba(223,223,223, 0.91) , -1px -1px 6px rgba(223,223,223, 0.91) ;
    }
    .dp-table.dp-months-table tr>*:hover {
        color: #0089ec;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f63e015aa3.js"></script>

<span style="position: fixed; color: red; font-weight: 800;width: 100%; text-align: center">
Resize the window to see the problem (<i>smaller</i>)
</span>

<div class="dp-container">
    <div class="dp-header">
        <a><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-3x dp-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <span class="dp-title"><a class="dp-month">June</a> <i class="dp-year">2017</i></span>
        <a><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-3x dp-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid dp-body">
        <table  class="table table-sm dp-table dp-months-table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="january"><div>January</div></td>
                <td class="february"><div>February</div></td>
                <td class="march"><div>March</div></td>
                <td class="april"><div>April</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="may"><div>May</div></td>
                <td class="june"><div>June</div></td>
                <td class="july"><div>July</div></td>
                <td class="august"><div>August</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="september"><div>September</div></td>
                <td class="october"><div>October</div></td>
                <td class="november"><div>November</div></td>
                <td class="december"><div>December</div></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-sm dp-table dp-days-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><div>Sun</div></th>
                    <th><div>Mon</div></th>
                    <th><div>Tue</div></th>
                    <th><div>Wed</div></th>
                    <th><div>Thu</div></th>
                    <th><div>Fri</div></th>
                    <th><div>Sat</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="dp-week-num"><div>8</div></th>
                <td disabled><div>28</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>29</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>30</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>31</div></td>
                <td><div>1</div></td>
                <td><div>2</div></td>
                <td><div>3</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="dp-week-num"><div>9</div></th>
                <td><div>4</div></td>
                <td><div>5</div></td>
                <td><div>6</div></td>
                <td><div>7</div></td>
                <td><div>8</div></td>
                <td><div>9</div></td>
                <td><div>10</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="dp-week-num"><div>10</div></th>
                <td><div>11</div></td>
                <td><div>12</div></td>
                <td><div>13</div></td>
                <td><div>14</div></td>
                <td><div>15</div></td>
                <td><div>16</div></td>
                <td><div>17</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="dp-week-num"><div>11</div></th>
                <td><div>18</div></td>
                <td><div>19</div></td>
                <td class="today selected"><div>20</div></td>
                <td><div>21</div></td>
                <td><div>22</div></td>
                <td><div>23</div></td>
                <td><div>24</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="dp-week-num"><div>12</div></th>
                <td><div>25</div></td>
                <td><div>26</div></td>
                <td><div>27</div></td>
                <td><div>28</div></td>
                <td><div>29</div></td>
                <td><div>30</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>1</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="dp-week-num"><div>13</div></th>
                <td disabled><div>2</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>3</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>4</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>5</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>6</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>7</div></td>
                <td disabled><div>8</div></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="dp-footer">
        <button type="button" class="dp-btn dp-btn-today">Today</button>
        <button type="button" class="dp-btn dp-btn-clear">Clear</button>
        <button type="button" class="dp-btn dp-btn-close">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('div.dp-container .dp-table.dp-days-table').hide();
    $('div.dp-container').each((i,container)=>{
    $(container).find('.dp-title').on('click', e=>{
     $(container).find('.dp-body>table.dp-table.dp-days-table').toggle();
     $(container).find('.dp-body>table.dp-table.dp-months-table').toggle();
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note:** I want the *body* div to resize with the window

Comment: Set: `margin:auto` on the `table`.

Comment: look at the flexbox model

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary code in your example you should be using HTML codes to display < and > as standard characters &lt; and &gt;. or you risk breaking something. Have no idea why you included script libraries when you're not using any of it in your example. Give me a min I'll try and cut it down. My example will be a bit more basic though...

Comment: @mr.void I tried flexbox and it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: DrunkenPoney so you used display:flex on the container an flex:1 on the element you want to strech?

Comment: @LukeJonGibson It's cause this code is just a part of my page. I'm not gonna put the whole page here. And if I putted '<' and '>' it's cause in my real page these two are arrows and I use font awesome 5.

Comment: @mr.void Yes I used display: flex on container and I tried many different things on the element I want to stretch. It doesn'T change anything exept that my container is not centered anymore

Comment: Not being funny. But then why include it in your snippet? Including code that's irrelevant to the problem just makes it harder for people to help. Just as a rule of thumb, if you know 100% that a piece of code has no effect on the outcome of your snippet, cut it out. Yeah I'll try and explain in my answer.

Comment: @mr.void God! I'm stupid I just realized I put fixed keyword on position and not on display. xD But anyway it doesn't work either: my body div goes under the footer div.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for playin around?

Comment: @mr.void I've just added the link to the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to fullscreen it or view it in the editor as the preview doesn't display correctly. But that should sort your problem.

I cut off all excess code so it's easier to see what's going on.

There's a great guide to flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The basics of it **display: flex;** This defines a flex container; It enables a flex context for all its direct children.

**flex-direction** row is already the default setting displaying items left to right.

**flex-wrap** By default, flex items will all try to fit onto one line. So this is set to **wrap.**

Spacing the items inside the flexbox **.flexbox item** by defining the width as 28% or any division that is less than a third and more than a fourth of the total width minus the margin, approximately between 26-33% will make the flexbox display rows of three.

### Alignment:

**justify-content** This defines the alignment along the main axis.

**align-items** This defines the default behaviour for how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line.

**align-content** This aligns a flex container's lines within

> **flex-start (default):** items are packed toward the start line
>
> **flex-end:** items are packed toward to end line
>
> **center:** items are centered along the line
>
> **space-between:** items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is
>   on the start line, last item on the end line
>
> **space-around:** items are evenly distributed in the line with equal
>   space around them. Note that visually the spaces aren't equal, since
>   all the items have equal space on both sides. The first item will have
>   one unit of space against the container edge, but two units of space
>   between the next item because that next item has its own spacing that
>   applies.

***Quote from CSS Tricks***

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1%;
  background: #ff0000;
}

header span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav {
  background: #008000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox item {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  background: #00ffff;
  margin: 1% 0;
  align-self: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer item {
  padding: 1% 2%;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <main>
    <header class="nav">
      <span>&lt; Prev / Next &gt;</span>
    </header>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <item>td-1</item>
      <item>td-2</item>
      <item>td-3</item>
      <item>td-1</item>
      <item>td-2</item>
      <item>td-3</item>
      <item>td-1</item>
      <item>td-2</item>
      <item>td-3</item>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <item>Open</item>
      <item>Clear</item>
      <item>Close</item>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: That's not what I want. The thing is that I dont want to resize the *items* and/or anything exept the *body* (*flexbox*) and I want the table(*body*) to resize with the window. I mean in your snippet the items goes outside the container

Comment: I dont want it to work only on fullscreen. Look at the update I made.

Comment: Sigh, that's not the issue, besides I fixed it anyway. If you're too lazy to fixgure out how this fixes your problem, that's your fault not mine.

Comment: If I need to spell it out, just change the width/height to whatever you need. They're completely flexible, the important part is already determined, the flex attribute and getting the items inside it to display at 1/3rd of the container width and the middle table to stretch into the gap between the header and the footer. You can make it look good at 200px width to 4K by just setting the padding and margin of the elements differently, like I've now done. Which should now maintain it's aspect ration no matter if the screen is 200 - 2000px+ wide.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/fn1njg

Answer (score 0):

I decided to challenge myself see if I could go the distance and make the datepicker from the code I'd made in the same sort of style as your fiddle. ALthough I'll leave it here before I get into too much detail lol.

A bit of a pointless exercise when you can simply type...

```
<input type="date">
```

...and HTML5 will build a datepicker for you. Which can be styled.

More about that here: http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date

Still it was fun to play with.

### Date Picker in Flexbox CSS

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.flexbox.day').hide();
  $('dates.date').hide();
  $("switchButton").click(function() {
    $('.flexbox.day').slideToggle();
    $('.flexbox.month').slideToggle();
    $('dates.date').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&subset=greek,latin-ext');
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: rgba(132, 141, 148, 0.82);
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

header i {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

header a {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3vmax;
  width: 30%;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav {
  background: rgba(160, 61, 78, 0.13);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.flexbox item {
  width: 27%;
  padding: 0.5% 1%;
  background: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.8);
  margin: 0.1% 0.1%;
  align-self: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(84, 184, 242, 0.91), 1px 1px 6px rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.91), -1px -1px 6px rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.91);
}

.flexbox day {
  width: 14%;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: rgba(233, 255, 255, 0.9);
  margin: 0.1% 0.1%;
  align-self: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(84, 184, 242, 0.91), 1px 1px 6px rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.91), -1px -1px 6px rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.91);
}

dates {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

dates date {
  line-height:1;
  width: 14%;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.8);
  margin: 0.1% 0.14511999%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(84, 184, 242, 0.91), 1px 1px 6px rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.91), -1px -1px 6px rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.91);
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgba(78, 61, 78, 0.13);
  padding: 0.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer item {
  padding: 0.5% 1%;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 27%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0.3% 0;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  align-self: space-between;
}

.footer item:hover {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(174, 236, 255, 0.8);
}

.flexbox item:hover,
.flexbox day:hover,
dates date:hover {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(174, 236, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <header class="nav">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><input type="number" min="1900" max="2100" step="1" value="2017"></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </header>
    <div class="flexbox month">
      <item>Jan</item>
      <item>Feb</item>
      <item>Mar</item>
      <item>Apr</item>
      <item>May</item>
      <item>June</item>
      <item>July</item>
      <item>Aug</item>
      <item>Sep</item>
      <item>Oct</item>
      <item>Nov</item>
      <item>Dec</item>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox day">
      <day>Mon</day>
      <day>Tue</day>
      <day>Wed</day>
      <day>Thu</day>
      <day>Fri</day>
      <day>Sat</day>
      <day>Sun</day>
    </div>
    <dates class="date">
      <date>1</date>
      <date>2</date>
      <date>3</date>
      <date>4</date>
      <date>5</date>
      <date>6</date>
      <date>7</date>
      <date>8</date>
      <date>9</date>
      <date>10</date>
      <date>11</date>
      <date>12</date>
      <date>13</date>
      <date>14</date>
      <date>15</date>
      <date>16</date>
      <date>17</date>
      <date>18</date>
      <date>19</date>
      <date>20</date>
      <date>21</date>
      <date>22</date>
      <date>23</date>
      <date>24</date>
      <date>25</date>
      <date>26</date>
      <date>27</date>
      <date>28</date>
      <date>29</date>
      <date>30</date>
      <date>31</date>
    </dates>
    <div class="flexbox day">
      <day>Mon</day>
      <day>Tue</day>
      <day>Wed</day>
      <day>Thu</day>
      <day>Fri</day>
      <day>Sat</day>
      <day>Sun</day>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <item>
        <switchButton>Days/Months</switchButton>
      </item>
      <item>Clear</item>
      <item>Close</item>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: But I don't think the date input allows you to select a whole week or a whole month and that's what I'm trying to do right now and once the HTML and CSS part is done it's pretty simple to select a whole week and/or month using javascript.